# Should i learn Bootstrap in 2024

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm learning web development online and I was wondering if should start learning Bootstrap, I've been told by some people that I should learn Bootstrap and some told me not to.

do you think learning Bootstrap is good nowadays, even tho I've looked for jobs on Linkedin and didn't find a job requiring Bootstrap knowledge.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. We're not a discussion forum and this question is off topic.

Comment: That said, the answer is simple: Do you have a reason to learn it? I find it a great site-building platform and have used it for hundreds of fun projects. I also find it a good guide for modern best practice with regard to layout and accessibility (in conjunction with MDN and others). As far as jobs go... Bootstrap knowledge is useful but not terribly impressive. More impressive is an understanding of the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript principles _in use_ by Bootstrap.